# why my user can't be authenticated after register,but can after login

Tags: python, django, authentication

I started an app named 'blogs' as a programming book required,when I finished the 'register' function which can register a user and login with it.I found that the user can be added to database normally,but it can't be authenticated.but when I used the username login normally,it can work!I checked my codes for many times,but I can't find the fault.Please give me some help,thank you very much!

Here are my codes:

*users:views.py:*

```
def register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username, password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request,authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:index'))
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'users/register.html',context)
```

*users:register.html:*

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">register</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'blogs:index' %}" />
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

*blogs:base.html:*

```
Welcome to blog -
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    hello,{{ user.username }} -
    <a href="{% url 'users:log_out' %}">logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:register' %}">register - </a>
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">login </a>
{% endif %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get `'password1'` from? Probably you have it in your login.html and confuse. Change that line with `authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username, password=new_user.password)` . Hope it will help.